# list index out of range - error says from line "cmd = tokens[0]"

Tags: python

#------------------------create------------------------------

def create(car_id, make, model, year, body_type):

```
row = [car_id, make, model, year, body_type]
data.append(row)

return f"created car with id {car_id}"
```

#------------------------delete-----------------------------------

def delete (car_id, id_to_delete):

```
global c_id

for row in data:
    c_id = row[0]
    if car_id == id_to_delete:
        data.remove(row)
        break
pass
```

#------------------------selecting-------------------------------

def select_by_id(c_id):

```
for row in data:
    car_id = row[0]
    
    if car_id == c_id:
        selection.append(row)
        
        return f"selected car with id {c_id}"
```

def select_all():

```
global selection
selection = data
```

#-----------------------input loop------------------------------------

def input_loop():

```
while(1):
    line = input()
    tokens = line.split()
    
    cmd = tokens[0]
    
    if cmd == "create":
        print(tokens[1:])
        
        '''
        car_id = tokens[1]
        make = tokens[2]
        model = tokens[3]
        year = tokens[4]
        
        result = create(car_id, make, model, year)
        '''
        result = create(*tokens[1:5])
        print(result)
        
    elif cmd == "exit":
        print("goodbye")
        break
    elif cmd == "update":
        result = update(*tokens[1:4])
    else:
        print("invalid or not implemented command: {cmd}")
```

input_loop()

#--------------------------------updating----------------------

def update(car_id, attr, val):

```
row = get_row(car_id)
        
        
if row:
            
        print(f"updating{attr}")
        
        i = headers.index(attr)
        print(f"index: {i}")
        
        
        print(row[i])
        row[i] = val
        pass
```

#------------------------print selection------------------------------

def print_selection():

```
headers = ['id','make','model','year','body_type']

for row in selection:
    print(headers)
    print(row)
    
    
    
pass
```

#-------------------------main--------------------------------------

def main():

```
create("0", "Toyota", "Highlander", "2015")
create("1", "Toyota", "Highlander", "2016")
create("2", "Toyota", "Highlander", "2017")

delete("1")

result = select_by_id("1")
print(result)
result = select_by_id("2")
print(result)

print_selection()
```

main()
I keep on getting a list index out of range error, and I'm not sure why it's happening or where to fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[enter image description here]
error code

Comment: You've shown us many things that are probably not relevant to causing the problem, and you haven't actually shown the problem. (Your image didn't post properly, but please *do not post error messages as images*; copy and the entire error message and post it formatted as code.)

Comment: index out of range just means that you are trying to access an element that is not there. This would happen when you don't type in anything when prompted for an input at `line = input()` in your `input_loop` function